# Meteor 1.3 : Can't import plotly.js

Tags: meteor, import, npm, plotly, angular2-meteor

I am trying to load `plotly.js` on the client side in my angular2-meteor app (Meteor 1.3), and I can't figure out how to do so.
I've tried many variations of `imports 'plotly.js'`, `import { Plotly } from 'plotly.js'` and so on, but none of them seem to work on the client (did not test on server so far).

The file that imports plotly is in the `imports` folder, so that I can use it either on server or on client.

Compiler gives me "Cannot find module 'plotly.js'" for most of my tries,  `imports 'plotly.js'` gives no error message, but the `Plotly` object is not defined.

Do you have any solution ? I'd like a real solution more than a quickfix or CDN loading, as this kind of issue seems to appear with a lot of npm packages. Thanks a lot !

Comment: How did you add Plotly?  Is is added as a meteor package, npm, or directly using script tags in the HTML?  How you will most likely go about using it depends on how it was added.  If you are using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly), then you would do `import {Plotly} from 'plotly';`.  This looks like it's a function that requires you to pass in a userid and api key to get the actual object.

Comment: I used npm. I am using `plotly.js` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly.js), which is the graphing library used by plotly. `plotly` is only (at least as I understood) a connector their cloud-based API, and it is a different package.
So I am trying to load only the graphing library. I think that issue comes from the fact that the npm version is only meant for server and provides no client side export.

Comment: well, according to the docs there, it looks like you would do something like `import {plotly} from plotly.js/lib/core`.  Check your `./node_modules/plotly.js` folder, specifically if there is an `index.js` in `lib/core`.  It should be there w/ an export in it.

Comment: Hi, I could not get this to work, though the `lib` folder indeed contain an `index.js` file. `plotly` is still undefined
Do you know how to simply load the .js file, without npm ? I can't event get that working...

Comment: Ok, it's "learn to fish" time. ES6 module loading simply takes a .js file and loads what's been exported. So, if I look at the source for poly.js (link you provided above), I see there is no `index.js` in the root, but there is on in `/lib`. In that file, I see it exports something called `Core`. You can follow that to ultimately exports that happen in src/core.  There you can see that the `Core` object that is being exported is really a mash of a bunch of functions pulled out of a `Plotly` variable being pulled in from src/plotly.  So, try `import {Core} from plotly.js/lib/core`.

Comment: Tried, still not working :) I understand your reasonning and I also don't understand why this won't work. `Core` is undefined in my client code (still did not test on the server, but usually I have no problem with server side).
 Maybe it is an issue with Meteor or Angular, I opened up an issue [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/347)/

Comment: I also tried I tried `import { Core } from 'plotly.js/lib'` too, it gives me `package.json:157Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`. 
It seems that `fs.ReadStream` is undefined, maybe because the package is not meant for client side I guess ? At least it seems to load something...